# How will i pass an array as key to __set magic method

Tags: php

I have a php singleton session class as follows.

```
class Session {

    static private $_instance = NULL;

    private function __construct() 
    {
        session_start();
    }

    /**
    * Prevents the class from being cloned
    * @return NULL
    */
    private function __clone() { }

    /**
    * Returns the singleton instance of this class
    * @return Session
    */
    public static function getInstance() 
    {
        if (!self::$_instance) {
            self::$_instance = new Session();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function __get($key) {
        if (isset($_SESSION[$key])) {
            return $_SESSION[$key];
        }
        return NULL;
    }

    public function __set($key, $value) 
    {
        $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function __isset($key) {
        return isset($_SESSION[$key]);
    }

    public function __unset($key) {
        unset($_SESSION[$key]);
    }


}
```

I can create an object as follows

```
$session = Session::getInstance();
$session->name = 'some name';
```

I can also get the value like

```
echo $session->name;
```

The problem is, i want to pass an array to this object and it is not working. for example, i wan to set something like

```
$_SESSION['user']['data'] = array('name'=>'some name',"empId"=>'123');
```

I am trying like this.

```
$session->['user']['data'] = array('name'=>'some name',"empId"=>'123');
```

but it is not working. Could you please suggest what is wrong.

Comment: `$session->user = array('data' => array('name'=>'some name',"empId"=>'123'));`

Comment: @Rufinus : why haven't you posted it as answer?

Comment: @Rufinus What if you then try and set `$session->user = array('somekey'=>array('data'));` - won't that overwrite the first data?

Comment: @DaveRandom of course it will, if you want to add something it would simple be `$session->user['data']['key'] = 'foobar';`

@Gaurav: becouse its to short, and i didnt had the mood to write more. ... besides, from new users you seldom get the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 3):

The workaround in this case would be to use:

```
public function &__get($key) {
    if (isset($_SESSION[$key])) {
        return & $_SESSION[$key];
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

You need to modify the `__get()` method, because an assignment like

```
$session->user['data'] = ...
```

will actually retrieve the `[user]` key, and then try to assign a new subarray `[data]` to that temporary array result.

Also note that `$session->['user']['data']` is invalid syntax. You either need `$session->user['data']` or `$session->{'user'}['data']`.

Anyway, I think it is probably not a good idea to use a wrapper if you often want to do assignments like that. (I do actually have something very similar.)

Comment: But i need to add a new key or update an existing value at a later time. So i will loose all existing data right?  $session->user['scores'] = something....

Answer (score 0):

```
$session->user = array('data' => array('name'=>'some name',"empId"=>'123'));
```

Make sure you don't overwrite anything else in `user` you want to keep

Comment: But i need to add a new key or update an existing value at a later time. So i will loose all existing data right?

Comment: All data, that is assign to `user`, yes, but you should be able to merge several arrays together.

Comment: `$session->user['data']['newkey'] = 'newval';`